# Why wouldn't I disable AAR Affinity on Azure web sites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

As default when deploying a new website, AAR Affinity is enabled to allow clients to reach the same web server instance over and over again. I'm wondering why this is enabled by default and if I ever need this feature. As I understand it, session storage and similar, aren't available on Azure. If you'd want this kind of behavior, Microsoft recommends using Redis as shared storage. My question is, what are the benefits of using AAR Affinity and any reasons not to disable it? Running without it, would make load balancing more evenly distributed as well.

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand it, session storage and similar, aren't available on Azure

In-memory session storage is just code running in ASP.NET, and is available on Azure Websites / Web Apps. If you were relying on this functionality then you'd need to leave the option enabled, otherwise you'd have a different session if you hit a different server.

Additionally, if you're using some form of in-memory cache then you'd want the same user to come back to the same server to improve cache hits.

Comment: But I guess you are not guaranteed to hit the same web server instance on the following request (even with AAR Affinity). And there's no session transfer supported on Azure, so cannot really see how session storage can be utilized without Redis or another form of external cache.

Comment: AAR affinity sets a cookie on your computer to make sure you hit the same server on a subsequent request (that's its main purpose). The only reason you wouldn't hit the same server is if that server didn't exist. It wouldn't be reliable or recommended, but it would still work.

Comment: But you're not sure that server still exists on the following request. That's my whole point in asking. If you cannot rely on the same server being available and there's no session transfer between instances, I don't see any point in enabling AAR Affinity.

Comment: Statistically the server will still be there on the next request, short of a scaling instruction or hardware failure. It's no more or less likely to be there than any other server in the cloud or running in your own datacentre. One of our app pools has been running for the past 5 days, which means that if you were logged in and active then your session would have been available for all that time.

Comment: I'm not condoning these practices as good, I'm just telling you that they exist. If you were making a line of business app where you had a fixed number of users for a fixed duration and the cost of them losing their session was minimal (retry action) then I could see companies choosing this method as opposed to ensuring that all of their session objects could be serialized as it might be a "cheaper" solution

Answer (score 0):

> What are the benefits of using ARR Affinity and any reasons not to disable it?

In the PaaS world, where your PaaS VM instances can be restarted for various reasons, it's not a good idea to store session information in memory. However, ARR Affinity is a way to support (with some limitations) those applications that were designed as session-sensitive (a.k.a stateful) apps.

You are right:

> Running without it, would make load balancing more evenly distributed as well.

HTH :)